# "Frac" function bug in Delphi?

Tags: function, delphi

In Delphi when I try to do this:

```
tmp := Frac(Frac(135.45)*100);
```

I see that it returns 1, when I expected 0. Why? `tmp` in this case is a `Real` variable.

Also, I used the below code to receive a visual confirmation:

```
Dialogs.ShowMessage(Format('Frac1=%f  Frac2=%f', [Frac(Frac(135.45)*100), Frac(45)]));
```

What is wrong? Is it a Delphi bug?

Comment: Probably, the actual outcome is something like `0.99999999999999999999` which output as `1`; and `0.45*100 = 44.99999999999999`

Comment: You can check for `1.0 - tmp` to see the difference

Comment: It's not a bug. It's an inevitable consequence of using binary floating point data types. Your number is not representable exactly. Read the answers carefully at the dupe.

Comment: Thank you all. It's how Bychenko responds. Because it is a real number, decimal values persist and cause the error.

Comment: There's nothing decimal here at all. It's a binary representation.